# What value should lightdm have in screensaver-timeout= to stop the monitor from turning off?

Tags: greeter, lock

I want to stop the monitor from turning off in the login and lock screen.

On the lightdm config file there is this line:

screensaver-timeout=

I tried to put a value of 0 and -1, but both make the screen turn off after 10 minutes.

What is the value to stop the monitor turn off?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry in the login screen! Will update answer

Answer (score 1):

the Elementary OS answer to this (instead of the terminal answer) is

`settings -> power -> set to never turn off monitor!`

Comment: It does not help, still monitor turns off after 10 mins. Tested both on LOKI and JUNO Beta2.

Comment: Well if it's a software bug then you'll need to report it as one. If this setting is available but doesn't work then it's a bug.